# Particular data of linked list is not printing

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list :

```
struct Vote{
    char vote_name[20];
    unsigned char prevHash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char names[10][20]; //10 names, 20 bytes each name
    int results_vote[10];
    struct Vote *next;
}*vote_head;
```

When I add more then one element in this structure, I cant more printf `char vote_name[20]`. To add a second and etc elements to the list, I wrote this code:

```
    struct Vote *currentBlock = vote_head;
    while(currentBlock->next)
    {
        currentBlock=currentBlock->next; 
    }
    struct Vote *newBlock=malloc(sizeof(struct Vote));
    currentBlock->next=newBlock;
    int n;
    char name[20];
    char nameliste[20];
    printf("vote name?");
    scanf("%s", name);
    strcpy(newBlock->vote_name, name);
    printf("number of candidates? (max 10 names)");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%s",newBlock->vote_name); <--- there is working
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        printf("name of candidate?");
        scanf("%s",nameliste);
        strcpy(newBlock->names[i],nameliste);
        memset(newBlock,0,sizeof(newBlock->results_vote));
        printf("%s",newBlock->vote_name); <--- nothing is happening

    }
```

BUT: before a loop for I can printf vote_name, but inside the loop or after, I don’t get anything. Like a line with a printf does not exist. Other data of this list are working good.

Comment: What is this `memset(newBlock,0,sizeof(newBlock->results_vote));` for?

Comment: @hanie First of all there's no such thing as `Null`, second it can't be `NULL` because it's not inherently a pointer. The problem is the first character becomes `0` after the call to `memset()` and hence it's effectievly an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong here, but that may be because of the way you've cut it down from the full example.

The first problem is that you don't allocate any memory for `currentBlock`. But since you never actually use `currentBlock`, we can cut that all out.

The actual problem seems to be in your `memset` line. Based on the size, you seem to be trying to blank the `results_vote` field, but because you've just passed in the address of `newBlock`, you've blanked the first field in the structure, which is `vote_name`.

I think you want:

```
memset(newBlock->results_vote, 0, sizeof(newBlock->results_vote));
```

Though hard to be sure without the full code.

Comment: How do you know that no memory was allocated for `currentBlock`? It's assigned to `vote_head` which might be pointing to a perfectly healthy block of memory.

Comment: Which is why I wrote '...but that may be because of the way you've cut it down from the full example.'

Comment: Thank you a lot, the problem was just for the place of ```newBlock``` was supposed to be ```newBlock->results_vote``` .

Answer (score 2):

> printf("%s",newBlock->vote_name); <--- nothing is happening

as said in a comment in

```
    memset(newBlock,0,sizeof(newBlock->results_vote));
    printf("%s",newBlock->vote_name); <--- nothing is happening
```

the *memset* does not raz *newBlock->results_vote* as you expected but the first bytes of *newBlock*, and the beginning of *newBlock* is the field *vote_name*, so the *printf* does nothing

just do

```
memset(newBlock,0,sizeof(*newBlock));
```

just after the *malloc* and not later

Of course you can also do

```
memset(newBlock->results_vote,0,sizeof(newBlock->results_vote));
```

---

Out of hat

- I encourage you to check the result of your *scanf* to be sure a valid value was enter
- also limit the length when you read a string to not write out of the receiver ("%19s" when the string can contain 20 characters including the final null character)
- check *n* less than 11 to be compatible with the vector sized 10

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
memset(newBlock,0,sizeof(newBlock->results_vote));
```

indicates that you do not understand what `memset()` does. Please read at least the manual for every function you use, [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html).

The `memset()` function will set every byte to the second argulemt in the memory pointed to by the first argument up to the size that you specify as the third argument. So it's unclear why you are doing that.

Be careful when using the `sizeof` operator because it's often misunderstood.

When you call `memset()` you are corrupting the structure's memory in a very difficult to predict way, but basically you are writing `0` to the first 10 bytes of the structure. If I had to guess then you have set the first byte of `vote_name` to `0` which means that it is effectively an empty string — *please also read about what is considered a [string](/questions/tagged/string) in the [c](/questions/tagged/c) language*).

If you need to reset the content of each block you must do it in a careful way, preventing to overwrite the `next` member because if you do so, it's no longer a linked list as you've lost the links.

Again please read the manuals, for instance you have to check for the return value of `malloc()` to ensure you really allocated a valid memory block, you shouldn't ignore the result of `scanf()` either. Given the parameters of `scanf()` don't you think you are using a unnecessary variable to store the result? Finally the `scanf()` specifiers can help you prevent an overflow, something that you would know if you read the manual.